# how to list the current used collection in MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb

I want to export the current collection I'm using but i don't remember the name of it.

as far as i know, if i want to show the current DB that I'm using in MongoDB shell i would simply type:

`> db`

and the output would be:

`current used db name`

however when i type collection and execute it, it doesn't work.

my question: is there a command that is similar to db command functionality in MongoDB shell that shows the current used collection?

Comment: There is no current collection command in the console, You can just go through the executed queries history(Just keep pressing up arrow) and find out the collection name.

Comment: It's not like I'm lazy or something, i just wanna automate the process of it later in a script to save time but thanks for making it clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `mongo` shell, you switch to a database using the `use xxx` command. However, there is no corresponding command for collections since you cannot "go into" a collection like you can with databases.

It's a similar concept to most SQL shell. You can switch databases (typically using `USE XXX;`) but you cannot "go into" a specific SQL table. See the related [MySQL USE statement documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html).

You can list the available collections in your current database using `show collections`.